# regex has extra slashes

Tags: python, regex

Here is the line of code I am using to try to split by two strings.

```
name = str(re.search(r'/(?<=currencies\/)([^/])+(?=\/#markets|$)/', str(tag)).group(0))
```

and here is the string I want to split.

```html
<a href="/currencies/ripple/#markets" class="price" data-usd="0.303049255753"
 data-btc="8.78557136457e-05">$0.303049</a>
```

I am getting `/ripple/` but I want just `ripple` .
I know I could just use `.replace()`, but I am trying to learn regex so if someone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show the input (the string(s) to process), desired and actual output and the Python code you are using (all as properly formatted text in the question).

Comment: Then don't include the slashes in your search string. Without, you get just `ripple`.

Comment: You are using `/` as regex delimiters, but Python regex patterns do not require delimiters, they are specified using string literals. See [`(?<=currencies/)[^/]+(?=/#markets|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/ZoAOo4/1)

Comment: Don't parse html with a regex, use an html parser like beautifulsoup - https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/

Answer (score 4):

You need to put the `+` modifier inside your capture group (instead of outside) and select group 1 instead of 0:

```
>>> re.search(r'/(?<=currencies\/)([^/]+)(?=\/#markets|$)/', str(tag)).group(1)
'ripple'
```